# android: цвет заднего фона при появлении диалогового окна

Tags: android, android-dialog

Как можно изменить цвет фона родительской activity при появлении dialog? Сейчас фон затемняется ([image])

как можно "засветлить его" как здесь : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

За затемнение диалога отвечает параметр dimAmount.

Пример 1:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Title").setMessage("Message").create();
alertDialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0);
alertDialog.show();
```

Пример 2:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert.TestDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

и

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert_TestDialogTheme).
        setTitle("Title").
        setMessage("Message").
        create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

Определите следующие стили в файле `styles.xml`

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Вставьте в конструктор

```
AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubProducts.this, R.style.CustomDialog);
```

Программно

```
myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16187005/5330439)